# What is the search mechanism in "join attributes by location"?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

While running *join attributes by location*, we can either choose one to many or one to one mapping. In One-to-one, it assigns the first located features value.
 What is meant by first located feature? How is this locating or searching carried out?

Comment: What GIS are you using?

Comment: It's QGIS 3.2.2 Bonn

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for details.

Answer (score 3):

It is safe to interpret it as "a random feature at the same location". The data provider (shapefile, database etc) comes into play and decide the "first" returned item, which can be different each time.